# Implicit fitting with scipy.odr

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

By using `scipy.odr` ([link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html)), I would like to perform a fit by assuming an implicit model function. For simplicity, let us assume a linear model, namely

y = a*x + b, (1)

and we are interested in its implicit form, i.e.

a*x + b - y = 0. (2)

In the following I show my code:

```
import scipy.odr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 1
b = 2

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
y = a * x + b + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))

# Define function for scipy.odr
def func(p, var):        
    x, y = var
    a, b = p    
    return a * x + b - y

# Fit the data using scipy.odr
Model = scipy.odr.Model(func, implicit=True)
Data = scipy.odr.Data(np.array([x,y]), 0)
Odr = scipy.odr.ODR(Data, Model, [a,b], maxit=10000)
```

From the last line of the code I get this error:

```
in _check(self)
    848             print(res.shape)
    849             print(fcn_perms)
--> 850             raise OdrError("fcn does not output %s-shaped array" % y_s)
    851 
    852         if self.model.fjacd is not None:

OdrError: fcn does not output [0, 50]-shaped array
```

I don't get what I should modify in the code. For sure there is something I'm not understanding, even if I carefully read the documentation.

**EDIT**:

I misunderstood the meaning of the `y` parameter in `scipy.odr.Data`. I thought it was the right-hand side of Eq. (2), but instead it is the dimensionality of the response. This is the correct line of code:

```
Data = scipy.odr.Data(np.array([x,y]), 1)
```

Now the code properly works.

Comment: you have sent a link, but not followed the basic usage of the link ?!?

Comment: Hi, I need something different from the "Basic usage" example. For example, a difference is that my model is not an explicit equation.