# How do you fit an implicit function on Python?

Tags: python, scipy

[image: iv_function_with_series_and_shunt_resistance]

This is the equation I have to fit. The function fit can be done on Origin but the process is tedious when working with several datasets of V_bias and I_out. I'm still a newbie, but I believe it can be much faster when it is done in Python.

What comes to mind is `scipy.odr` or `curve_fit`, but this is my first encounter with an implicit function, thus I'm really struggling with this.

```
    def func(var, params):
        x, y = var
        a, b, c, d = params
        return a - b * (np.exp((q *(x + y * c)) / m * kb * T) - 1) - (x + y * c) / d

    Model = scipy.odr.Model(func, implicit=True)
    Data = scipy.odr.Data([x,y], 1)
    Odr = scipy.odr.ODR(Data, Model, [a,b,c,d], maxit=10000)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-c60c09e793e1> in <module>
      1 Model = scipy.odr.Model(func, implicit=True)
      2 Data = scipy.odr.Data([x,y], 1)
----> 3 Odr = scipy.odr.ODR(Data, Model, [a,b,c,d], maxit=10000,)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\odr\odrpack.py in __init__(self, data, model, beta0, delta0, ifixb, ifixx, job, iprint, errfile, rptfile, ndigit, taufac, sstol, partol, maxit, stpb, stpd, sclb, scld, work, iwork)
    768         self.output = None
    769 
--> 770         self._check()
    771 
    772     def _check(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\odr\odrpack.py in _check(self)
    829         if self.model.extra_args is not None:
    830             arglist = arglist + self.model.extra_args
--> 831         res = self.model.fcn(*arglist)
    832 
    833         if res.shape not in fcn_perms:

<ipython-input-20-bbc4658d4df0> in func(var, params)
      1 def func(var, params):
----> 2     x, y = var
      3     a, b, c, d = params
      4     return a - b * (np.exp((q *(x + y * c)) / m * kb * T) - 1) - (x + y * c) / d

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Here's an attempt I borrowed from  [Implicit fitting with scipy.odr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585132/implicit-fitting-with-scipy-odr)

But it gives me that ValueError. How do I proceed?

Comment: Show us the code you have tried, even if it is not yet working properly. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i just edited it rn

Comment: Show us the `ValueError` stacktrace, including line numbers. The details matter. I imagine we're trying to unpack 4 values into two slots. The documentation explains that your func needs a signature of `fcn(beta, x) –> y`. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.odr.Model.html#scipy.odr.Model

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe use `print( var )` to see what you get in variable. It seems it has wrong number of data.

Comment: When using scipy functions like this you have to pay close attention to the documentation.  Your function has to follow those specs exactly.

Comment: I edited it right now. I'm still stuck, I've been searching for examples of scipy.ODR online but I haven't encountered it being used on an implicit function